# use jQuery .load(); to load only a portion of a document while using href as the paramenter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to do an AJAX call for a page

I know you can use AJAX to load a portion of a document by using this code:

```
$('#AJAX').load('/file-directory #content');
```

Instead of using the file path, I'm using  an href url that is from an anchor tag as the parameter that I'm passing through `.load();` I want to only load the `#content` of this document that I'm getting from the url (leaving the header and footer out, since they're already loaded)

the function I have is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var url = $(location).attr('href');

  $('#AJAX').load(url '#content');

});
```

I'm fairly new to jQuery, so some new eyes would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use string concatenation to combine the href value and the fragment

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var url = $(location).attr('href');

  $('#AJAX').load(url + ' #content');

});
```

Comment: That doesn't work. if you do an alert for it those parameters return the url with the string `#content` right after it with no spaces.

So if the url variable had `www.google.com` stored in it the alert would spit out `www.google.com#content` 

it gets viewed as a single string, instead of two parameters.

Comment: @ChrisHaugen if you see I've added a space at `' #content'`

Comment: No I did not, and I'm glad it was cleared up; I'm sure someone else might miss it in the future so I'm glad it's clear now. 

You sir are awesome! Thanks for teaching me how to concatenate!!!